# Add timestamp if any cell within adjacent range changes

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp, range

I need a function to add a timestamp, per the row, if any of the cells in the prior columns have changed.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row 2 | Row 2 | Row 2 | Row 2 | Row 2 | Row 2 |
| Row 3 | Row 3 | Row 3 | Row 3 | Row 3 | Row 3 |
| Row 4 | Row 4 | Row 4 | Row 4 | Row 4 | Row 4 |

F2 should be blank until anything in C2:E2 changes; if the data changes, then a timestamp added to F2. The check would be independent for each row, as in F3 would be blank until anything in C3:E3 changes, and F4 for C4:E4, etc...

I've seen several VB solutions but none that keep the timestamp in a static column when a checking a range of adjacent row cells for changes.

I tried creating a Timestamp from a previous solution and then setting a range in the cell formula, but I get `#NAME?` error.

```
Function Timestamp(Reference As Range)
    If Reference.Value <> "" Then
        Timestamp = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
    Else
        Timestamp = ""
    End If
End Function
```

`Timestamp(C2:E2)`

I should note, I also tried doing this without VB by using the following formula, which kept returning 0:

`=IF(OR(C2<>"",D2<>"",E2<>""),IF(F2="",NOW(),F2),"")`

Comment: You can't do it using a formula. When you say *"any of the cells in the prior columns have changed"*, it is assumed that the changes are manual i.e. the cells don't contain formulas. If that is the case, the `Worksheet Change` event is to be used. The tiny little details you haven't addressed explicitly: What should happen when a cell in a row changes and the time stamp is already present? Should it remain or be updated? What should happen if a row is cleared? Should the existing time stamp remain, be updated, or be cleared as well? Think about it and let us know by editing your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this with the [Worksheet.Change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) of the worksheet. A formula cannot determine if a cell changed or not.

You can use the following code and put it into the worksheet you want it to apply to:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' define Timestamp output column
    Const TimeStampColumn As String = "F"
    
    ' Observe C2:E1048576 for changes
    Dim RangeToObserve As Range
    Set RangeToObserve = Me.Range("C2:E" & Me.Rows.Count)
    
    ' Get all changed cells within the observed range
    Dim ChangedCells As Range
    Set ChangedCells = Application.Intersect(Target, RangeToObserve)
    
    If Not ChangedCells Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        On Error GoTo ENABLE_EVENTS ' make sure in case of errors events get enabled!
        
        Dim Row As Variant ' write timestamp for every changed row
        For Each Row In ChangedCells.Rows
            With Me.Cells(Row.Row, TimeStampColumn)
                .Value = Now()
                .NumberFormat = "dd\/mm\/yyyy hh:mm"
            End With
        Next Row
        
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    
ENABLE_EVENTS:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    If Err Then
        ' make sure to raise the error otherwise it will be silent and you will never notice that anything went wrong.
        Err.Raise Err.Number
    End If
End Sub
```

First we define a range we want to observe for changes `RangeToObserve`. Then find out which cells have changed in this observed range using `Intersect` and put them into `ChangedCells`.

Then we loop through all rows in `ChangedCells` and write the timestamp. Note never use `Format` (unless for displaying/printing purpose) this will turn the date into a text (which you can't calculate with). Always write the numeric value `now()` and then set the `NumberFormat` of the cell.

> *Note that we need to turn off events using `Application.EnableEvents = False` while changing cells within the `Worksheet.Change` event. otherwise you run into an (maybe) endless loop because the change within the event causes another `Worksheet.Change` event and so on.
>
> Also we need to take care that if any error occus the events get automatically turned on again. Otherwise they stay off until Excel closes.*

[image]